# Unable to open browser in selenium, throws a "null" message

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: structure]I have a framework that uses POM model and I have used a Utils folder structure which has DriverFactory,Constant and ReadConfigFile java files that configures and opens the browser. (code below)

Now before I did this (introducing the Utils package) the code was running fine and after introducing the Utils package i am getting "Unable to load browsernull" exception.

Not sure what is causing the problem. I am using a Mac machine.

**Constant.java** file:

```
    package Utils;

    public class Constant {

    public final static String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY = "properties/config.properties";

    public final static String GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"CucumberFramework/src/test/java/Resources/geckodriver";

    public final static String CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"CucumberFramework/src/test/java/Resources/chromedriver";


    }
```

**DriverFactory.java** file:

```
    package Utils;

    //import com.sun.java.util.jar.pack.Instruction;
    import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import pageObjects.AddIssuePage;
    import pageObjects.Login_Page;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    public class DriverFactory {

        public static WebDriver driver;
        public static Login_Page login_page;
        public static AddIssuePage addIssuePage;


        public WebDriver getDriver() {        

            try        
            {        
                ReadConfigFile file = new ReadConfigFile();
                String browserName = file.getBrowser();
                switch (browserName) {

                    case "firefox":

                        if (null == driver) {
                            System.setProperty("webdriver.geckodriver", Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                        }
                        break;

                    case "chrome":

                        if (null == driver) {

                            System.setProperty("webdriver.chromedriver", Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                            driver = new ChromeDriver();

                        }
                        break;

                }
            } catch (Exception e)

            {
                System.out.println("Unable to load browser" + e.getMessage());

            } finally        
            {
                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                login_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_Page.class);
            }

            return driver;
        }
    }
```

**ReadConfigFile.java** file:

```
package Utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadConfigFile {

    protected InputStream input = null;
    protected Properties prop = null;

    public ReadConfigFile () {

        try {
            ReadConfigFile.class.getClassLoader ().getResourceAsStream (Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(input);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }

    public String getBrowser(){

        if (prop.getProperty("browser") == null)    
            return " ";

        return prop.getProperty("browser");

    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Utils.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:63)
    at Steps.MasterHooks.setup(MasterHooks.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.run(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Utils.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:63)
    at Steps.MasterHooks.setup(MasterHooks.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenarioOutline.run(CucumberScenarioOutline.java:46)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:122)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

MasterHooks

```
package Steps;

import Utils.DriverFactory;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class MasterHooks extends DriverFactory {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        driver = getDriver();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {

        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace

Comment: I just added the stacktrace. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Can you debug the DriverFactory.class and check if you are getting browser value on :  
   String browserName = file.getBrowser();
And what are you having on config,properties ?

Comment: I have `browser=chrome` in config.properties

Comment: Which line is 63?

Comment: `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: can you share the code for Steps.MasterHooks.setup method?

Comment: I edited the OP

Comment: Can you add the debugger in Switch statement and check the browserName which is being passed?

Comment: It is not entering switch case browser is blank. I checked the code in my system. It is working fine after updating the code input as in the answer

Comment: I don't know what is wrong in my system, I still see the same message :(

Comment: I want to UP this question. I have same trouble, but NPE still throws after trying all proposed solution variants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Unable to load browsernull
```

...implies that the function `getBrowser()` is returning **null**.

I would suggest the changes:

- In **ReadConfigFile.java**:

  - Change:

    ```
    ReadConfigFile.class.getClassLoader ().getResourceAsStream (Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
    ```
  - To:

    ```
    File src = new File(Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(fis);
    ```
  - Change:

    ```
    public String getBrowser(){

        if (prop.getProperty("browser") == null)    
            return " ";

        return prop.getProperty("browser");

    }
    ```
  - To:

    ```
    public String getBrowser(){

        return prop.getProperty("browser");
    }
    ```
- In **Constant.java**

  - Change:

    ```
    public final static String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY = "properties/config.properties";
    ```
  - To:

    ```
    public final static String CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY = "./src/main/java/properties/config.properties";
    ```
- In **DriverFactory.java**

  - Change:

    ```
    "webdriver.geckodriver"
    ```
  - To:

    ```
    "webdriver.gecko.driver"
    ```
  - Change:

    ```
    "webdriver.chromedriver"
    ```
  - To:

    ```
    "webdriver.chrome.driver"
    ```

Comment: Ok so finally I figured it out. There was a trailing space after `browser=chrome` which caused the problem. I removed the space and added `webdriver.chrome.driver` and the code started running.

Comment: Hi. @moh17 , seems I have same trouble as You (I guess which course u'r passing). But: I have no space in config.properties, and I have webdriver.chrome.driver, BUT in result - same NPE. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, input instance variable of type Input Stream is assigned to null in Read config file class.
It should be assigned to input stream as given below.

```
package Utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadConfigFile {

    protected InputStream input = null;
    protected Properties prop = null;

    public ReadConfigFile () {

        try {
            input = ReadConfigFile.class.getClassLoader ().getResourceAsStream (Constant.CONFIG_PROPERTIES_DIRECTORY);
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(input);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }

    public String getBrowser(){

        if (prop.getProperty("browser") == null)    
            return " ";

        return prop.getProperty("browser");

    }

}
```

Comment: I still get the same exception even after I make the above changes

Comment: check the config properties file exist on the path with same name.

Comment: `browser = chrome` this is what I use in config properties file

Comment: have you checked the config file path?. it should be in the location properties/config.properties

Comment: Yes it is in the correct location. I have added a screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your properties/config.properties file?

From the infos you shared I was thinking about that:

When, in DriverFactory, you call

```
            ReadConfigFile file = new ReadConfigFile();
            String browserName = file.getBrowser();
```

In the getBrowser() there is:

```
   public String getBrowser(){

    if (prop.getProperty("browser") == null)    
        return " ";

    return prop.getProperty("browser");

}
```

So, if `prop.getProperty("browser")` is null, you are returning `" "` in browserName.

In the switch:

```
switch (browserName) {

                    case "firefox":

                        if (null == driver) {
                            System.setProperty("webdriver.geckodriver", Constant.GECKO_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
                            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
                            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                        }
                        break;

                    case "chrome":

                        if (null == driver) {

                            System.setProperty("webdriver.chromedriver", Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                            driver = new ChromeDriver();

                        }
                        break;

                }
            } catch (Exception e)

            {
                System.out.println("Unable to load browser" + e.getMessage());

            } finally        
            {
                driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                login_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_Page.class);
            }
```

I don't see any check in the case browserName is `" "` **or in another case** (I mean, there isn't a **default case)**. So, in case browserName is " " or something else different of "firefox" or "chrome" you go directly to the finally statement (the finally is always executed). In this case, because the driver is not instantiated, you will have a nullpointer exception in:

```
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I have `browser=chrome` in config.properties

Comment: @Mohan ok, but you have to be sure you instantiated the driver before your call in the line 63. Debug your code and be sure you call `driver = new ChromeDriver(); ` . And, as @DebanjanB said, this one `webdriver.chromedriver` should be `webdriver.chrome.driver`.